# Unable to get value of select menu in node.js

Tags: node.js

Unable to get value of select menu.When i get value of select menu and print it on console it says undefined

```
var express = require('express'),`
app = express();
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname +'/rad.html'));
});
app.post('/submit', function (req, res) {
 console.log(req.query.jobtype);
});
app.listen(2000);`
```

**Here is form**

```
`<form id="tableForm" action="/submit" method="POST">`
    `<div class="form-group">
<label>Type </label>
<select class="form-control" name="jobtype" required>
<option selected disabled>your job preference</option>
<option value="Part Time">Part Time</option>
<option value="Full Time">Full Time</option>
</select>
</div>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>`
```

Comment: req.body. jobtype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `req.query` use `req.body`, in your case it would be like

```
app.post('/submit', function (req, res) {
 console.log(req.body.jobtype);
});
```